# Is it safe to put code in a dependency property's setter block, or should I always use a callback method?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Is it safe to put code in a dependency property's setter block, or should I always use a callback method? WHAT'S THE DIFFERENCE?

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BodyText", typeof(string), typeof(EliteEditor), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, BodyText_Callback));

    public string BodyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BodyTextProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            /***** IS IT SAFE TO WRITE CODE HERE? *****/
            SetValue(BodyTextProperty, value); 
        }
    }

    private static void BodyText_Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /***** OR SHOULD I ALWAYS WRITE CODE HERE? *****/
    }
```

Comment: Generally you should not be doing any work in the CLR properties that expose dependency properties because WPF does not use those. It uses the dependency property system internally which will not invoke the CLR properties.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to say "setter". I will update post. 
Also, I don't know if it matters but I'm using UWP. 
Also, it appears that the code I place in the setter executes. I just don't know if it is appropriate to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in the setter block will *only* fire if you actually invoke that setter in C# (via `BodyText = someValue` somewhere). It does not fire if the runtime updates the dependency property (say through a binding update).

Technically you don't even *need to define the property*; the system will work just fine without it. The snippet generates it to make your life easier.

Thus you should always code against the callback; never having logic in the setter.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: I guess *need* is contextual, but generally people want to be able to set properties in XAML, which requires a CLR wrapper property.

Comment: @mikez Fair enough; just trying to point out why setter logic is such a bad idea :)

Comment: BradleyDotNET, can you test your understanding out in a UWP-based app? You say that the setter block does not fire unless invoked via C# code, but in my experience with UWP the setter block also fires when the property is set in xaml. Am I missing something? Are you specifically referring to WPF? Either way I will use a callback. I just want to understand why the wrapper is firing.

Comment: @LeBrownJones Set in XAML or the binding updates? As mike mentioned you need the CLR property to assign the binding object but I don't believe the setter is called on a binding update for UWP either.